Suspend on idle for a headless Ubuntu desktop
I have a AI/ML workstation running Ubuntu desktop. I use it remotely (within the same house) like a server so it has no keyboard, mouse or monitor connected to it. To save power, fan wear and dust accumulation, I'd like to suspend it when not in use. When I need it, I can use Wake on Lan.  However, what will be the basis for determining idleness? Low CPU/GPU activity can be a trigger but how do I convey that to Ubuntu?
Version: Ubuntu 23.10
Command:
gsettings list-recursively | grep -E 'sleep|suspend*'

Output:
org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files initial-sleep 15
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys suspend ['']
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys suspend-static ['XF86Sleep']
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor false
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 1500
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 900
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'suspend'


Just a heads up for you Ubuntu 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur) reaches End of Life on July 11, 2024. Time to upgrade. It gets more complex to upgrade after it reaches EOL.

@user68186 This is the output of the command:
org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files initial-sleep 15
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys suspend ['']
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys suspend-static ['XF86Sleep']
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor false
...continued...

...
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 1500
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 900
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'suspend'

@user68186 Question updated

The sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 1500 means it should go it sleep after 25 minutes of inactivity. Set it to 300 (5 minutes) and see if it works. You also need to enable lock screen using setting, if it is not already enabled.

Have you set up screen lock in Settings>Privacy>Screen>Screen Lock? You may have to set it up for suspend to work.
